# check CRC32 in transport stream PAT section - Java

Tags: java, mpeg, transport

I am developing application to parse transport stream in Java, and generate information from PAT, PMT, NIT tables.

I am able to get full PAT table section, but I don't know how to verify CRC appended in section.

How CRC is checked in table sections?

Is there any ready made API in Java for parsing TS? My goal is: Demultiplex TS, select few programs, remultiplex only selected programs and then stream.

Thanks

Comment: [java.util.zip.CRC32](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html)

Comment: Okay, I did that, the calculated CRC using java.util.zip.CRC32 is 0xf85e7c70 and appended CRC was 0x518b9bf4. So these are not matching!

Comment: I have to calculate CRC and then match it with appended CRC for equality right?

Comment: The control flow is `update*, getValue, {reset, update*, getValue}` with `reset` for a new CRC. If the getValues do not match I am lost. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I got it working:

```
public static final int [] CRC32_TABLE = {
    0x00000000, 0x04c11db7, 0x09823b6e, 0x0d4326d9,
    0x130476dc, 0x17c56b6b, 0x1a864db2, 0x1e475005,
    0x2608edb8, 0x22c9f00f, 0x2f8ad6d6, 0x2b4bcb61,
    0x350c9b64, 0x31cd86d3, 0x3c8ea00a, 0x384fbdbd,
    0x4c11db70, 0x48d0c6c7, 0x4593e01e, 0x4152fda9,
    0x5f15adac, 0x5bd4b01b, 0x569796c2, 0x52568b75,
    0x6a1936c8, 0x6ed82b7f, 0x639b0da6, 0x675a1011,
    0x791d4014, 0x7ddc5da3, 0x709f7b7a, 0x745e66cd,
    0x9823b6e0, 0x9ce2ab57, 0x91a18d8e, 0x95609039,
    0x8b27c03c, 0x8fe6dd8b, 0x82a5fb52, 0x8664e6e5,
    0xbe2b5b58, 0xbaea46ef, 0xb7a96036, 0xb3687d81,
    0xad2f2d84, 0xa9ee3033, 0xa4ad16ea, 0xa06c0b5d,
    0xd4326d90, 0xd0f37027, 0xddb056fe, 0xd9714b49,
    0xc7361b4c, 0xc3f706fb, 0xceb42022, 0xca753d95,
    0xf23a8028, 0xf6fb9d9f, 0xfbb8bb46, 0xff79a6f1,
    0xe13ef6f4, 0xe5ffeb43, 0xe8bccd9a, 0xec7dd02d,
    0x34867077, 0x30476dc0, 0x3d044b19, 0x39c556ae,
    0x278206ab, 0x23431b1c, 0x2e003dc5, 0x2ac12072,
    0x128e9dcf, 0x164f8078, 0x1b0ca6a1, 0x1fcdbb16,
    0x018aeb13, 0x054bf6a4, 0x0808d07d, 0x0cc9cdca,
    0x7897ab07, 0x7c56b6b0, 0x71159069, 0x75d48dde,
    0x6b93dddb, 0x6f52c06c, 0x6211e6b5, 0x66d0fb02,
    0x5e9f46bf, 0x5a5e5b08, 0x571d7dd1, 0x53dc6066,
    0x4d9b3063, 0x495a2dd4, 0x44190b0d, 0x40d816ba,
    0xaca5c697, 0xa864db20, 0xa527fdf9, 0xa1e6e04e,
    0xbfa1b04b, 0xbb60adfc, 0xb6238b25, 0xb2e29692,
    0x8aad2b2f, 0x8e6c3698, 0x832f1041, 0x87ee0df6,
    0x99a95df3, 0x9d684044, 0x902b669d, 0x94ea7b2a,
    0xe0b41de7, 0xe4750050, 0xe9362689, 0xedf73b3e,
    0xf3b06b3b, 0xf771768c, 0xfa325055, 0xfef34de2,
    0xc6bcf05f, 0xc27dede8, 0xcf3ecb31, 0xcbffd686,
    0xd5b88683, 0xd1799b34, 0xdc3abded, 0xd8fba05a,
    0x690ce0ee, 0x6dcdfd59, 0x608edb80, 0x644fc637,
    0x7a089632, 0x7ec98b85, 0x738aad5c, 0x774bb0eb,
    0x4f040d56, 0x4bc510e1, 0x46863638, 0x42472b8f,
    0x5c007b8a, 0x58c1663d, 0x558240e4, 0x51435d53,
    0x251d3b9e, 0x21dc2629, 0x2c9f00f0, 0x285e1d47,
    0x36194d42, 0x32d850f5, 0x3f9b762c, 0x3b5a6b9b,
    0x0315d626, 0x07d4cb91, 0x0a97ed48, 0x0e56f0ff,
    0x1011a0fa, 0x14d0bd4d, 0x19939b94, 0x1d528623,
    0xf12f560e, 0xf5ee4bb9, 0xf8ad6d60, 0xfc6c70d7,
    0xe22b20d2, 0xe6ea3d65, 0xeba91bbc, 0xef68060b,
    0xd727bbb6, 0xd3e6a601, 0xdea580d8, 0xda649d6f,
    0xc423cd6a, 0xc0e2d0dd, 0xcda1f604, 0xc960ebb3,
    0xbd3e8d7e, 0xb9ff90c9, 0xb4bcb610, 0xb07daba7,
    0xae3afba2, 0xaafbe615, 0xa7b8c0cc, 0xa379dd7b,
    0x9b3660c6, 0x9ff77d71, 0x92b45ba8, 0x9675461f,
    0x8832161a, 0x8cf30bad, 0x81b02d74, 0x857130c3,
    0x5d8a9099, 0x594b8d2e, 0x5408abf7, 0x50c9b640,
    0x4e8ee645, 0x4a4ffbf2, 0x470cdd2b, 0x43cdc09c,
    0x7b827d21, 0x7f436096, 0x7200464f, 0x76c15bf8,
    0x68860bfd, 0x6c47164a, 0x61043093, 0x65c52d24,
    0x119b4be9, 0x155a565e, 0x18197087, 0x1cd86d30,
    0x029f3d35, 0x065e2082, 0x0b1d065b, 0x0fdc1bec,
    0x3793a651, 0x3352bbe6, 0x3e119d3f, 0x3ad08088,
    0x2497d08d, 0x2056cd3a, 0x2d15ebe3, 0x29d4f654,
    0xc5a92679, 0xc1683bce, 0xcc2b1d17, 0xc8ea00a0,
    0xd6ad50a5, 0xd26c4d12, 0xdf2f6bcb, 0xdbee767c,
    0xe3a1cbc1, 0xe760d676, 0xea23f0af, 0xeee2ed18,
    0xf0a5bd1d, 0xf464a0aa, 0xf9278673, 0xfde69bc4,
    0x89b8fd09, 0x8d79e0be, 0x803ac667, 0x84fbdbd0,
    0x9abc8bd5, 0x9e7d9662, 0x933eb0bb, 0x97ffad0c,
    0xafb010b1, 0xab710d06, 0xa6322bdf, 0xa2f33668,
    0xbcb4666d, 0xb8757bda, 0xb5365d03, 0xb1f740b4
};

public void PATParse(){
    boolean crcMatched = false;
    int crc = 0xffffffff;
    System.out.print("Section Buffer: ");
    for(byte b : sectionBuffer) {
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ CRC32_TABLE[((crc >> 24) ^ (b & 0xff)) & 0xff];
        System.out.print("0x" + Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    if(crc == 0){
        crcMatched = true;
    }

    if(crcMatched){
        System.out.println("CRC is valid");
        for(int i = 8; i + 4 < sectionBuffer.length; i = i + 4){
            int programNumber = ((sectionBuffer[i] & 0xff) << 8) | (sectionBuffer[i + 1] & 0xff);
            int pid = ((sectionBuffer[i + 2] & 0x1f) << 8) | (sectionBuffer[i + 3] & 0xff);
            pat.put(programNumber, pid);
        }
    }
    sectionBuffer = null;
}
```

I took above logic for CRC validating from http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvbpsi.html